# "Nothing fetched" returned when running PHP SimpleTest on my localhost

Tags: php, simpletest

I'm trying to use [SimpleTest](http://www.simpletest.org/) to run a set of tests on a project, I always get "Nothing fetched" when running the tests on my localhost but it works totally fine when run these tests on a remote server.

I'm using on both my machine and the server Fedora 16 and Nginx, and i'm using the command line reporter to run these tests.

Comment: Post a snippet of the test to show what it is doing and where it is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method [setConnectionTimeout()](http://simpletest.org/api/SimpleTest/WebTester/WebTestCase.html#setConnectionTimeout) of class WebTestCase. It is intended to be used for these purposes. You call it before [get()](http://simpletest.org/api/SimpleTest/WebTester/WebTestCase.html#get) method to set socket timeout.

For example:

```
class ContinuousTestCase extends WebTestCase {
    function testSuccess() {
        $this->setConnectionTimeout(300);  // takes about 5 minutes
        $this->assertTrue($this->get('http://localhost/continuous.php'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed! all i had to do is to increase the DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT in the simpletest/user_agent.php, for some reason my localhost is slower than the remote server.